# Check if input is Tuple[int, int] or Iterable[Tuple[int, int]] in Python

Tags: python, input, typing, isinstance

This might be easy but I'm not sure how to do that. I have a method looking like this:

```py
def my_method(
    self,
    coords: Union[Tuple[int, int], Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]
):
    ...
```

that is, `my_method` needs a tuple of integers or something like a list of tuples of integers (those are some sort of coordinates). Is my typing correct for this?
But my main question, how do I check whether the input is only one tuple like `(1,1)` or something like `[(1,1),(1,2),..]` or `((1,1),(1,2),..)` or something similar? I heard about `isinstance`, but I couldn't figure out how to use this here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[1, 1]` isn't a tuple.

Comment: Oh yeah. my mistake. I will edit that.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to make the method only accept iterables of iterables. For example when you want to pass one set of coordinates you pass `[(1,1)]`. You then unpack it within the method body. This way you only have to consider one case in the method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought about that but I wasn't sure if that would be best practice in this case. Doing it like this would be easier on my side for sure though.